# InstallData works only once

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, installdata

I'm trying to **add customer attributes**. By struggling, my first attribute is added thanks to this : 
InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'code_client', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Code client',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'code_client')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

and extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="code_client" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

But then, I tried to add another attribute thanks to this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
        <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
<attribute code="code_client" type="string"/>
            <attribute code="raison_sociale" type="string"/>
        </extension_attributes>
    </config>
```

and InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'raison_sociale', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Raison sociale',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'raison_sociale')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

My new attribute is not in the database, installData only work once and I don't know why. Any ideas ?

**EDIT** : found a temporary solution : deleting my module in setup_module in database and then setup:upgrade with only my new attribute. Clearly, that's not the best solution, so if you guys have any advice :)

Answer (score 3):

It's default behaviour of **`InstallData`** it only execute once when your module register First Time.

I would recommend you to create **`upgradeData`**.

Check below reference to know about more.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/

Hope it will make you understand how Magento deals with **Setup Scripts**.